# Can you change the Block Drops when mined with a custom Item in a Fabric 1.16.5 Minecraft Mod

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I've been trying to make a Pickaxe that automatically smelts Blocks that you mine but my problem is that the blocks still drop the normal drop on top of the custom one.
Here is the class of the pickaxe:

```
import com.mojang.serialization.Decoder;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.item.v1.FabricItemSettings;
import net.minecraft.block.AbstractFurnaceBlock;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.BlockState;
import net.minecraft.entity.LivingEntity;
import net.minecraft.inventory.SimpleInventory;
import net.minecraft.item.*;
import net.minecraft.recipe.Recipe;
import net.minecraft.recipe.RecipeType;
import net.minecraft.recipe.SmeltingRecipe;
import net.minecraft.server.network.ServerPlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.server.world.ServerWorld;
import net.minecraft.util.Rarity;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class FirePickaxe extends PickaxeItem {
    public FirePickaxe(ToolMaterial material) {
        super(material, 7, -2.8F, new Item.Settings().group(ItemGroup.TOOLS).fireproof().maxCount(1).maxDamage(1024).
                rarity(Rarity.RARE));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean postHit(ItemStack stack, LivingEntity target, LivingEntity attacker) {
        target.setOnFireFor(5);
        return super.postHit(stack, target, attacker);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean postMine(ItemStack stack, World world, BlockState state, BlockPos pos, LivingEntity miner) {
        if (!world.isClient) {
            List<ItemStack> drops = Block.getDroppedStacks(state, (ServerWorld) world, pos, null, miner, stack);
            List<ItemStack> modifiedDrops = new ArrayList<>();

            for (ItemStack drop : drops) {
                ItemStack smeltedResult = getSmeltedResult(world, drop);
                if (!smeltedResult.isEmpty()) {
                    modifiedDrops.add(smeltedResult);
                }
            }
            drops.clear();

            for (ItemStack modifiedDrop : modifiedDrops) {
                Block.dropStack(world, pos, modifiedDrop);
            }
        }

        return super.postMine(stack, world, state, pos, miner);
    }

    private ItemStack getSmeltedResult(World world, ItemStack itemStack) {
        Optional<SmeltingRecipe> recipe = world.getRecipeManager().getFirstMatch(RecipeType.SMELTING, new SimpleInventory(itemStack), world);
        if (recipe.isPresent()) {
            ItemStack result = recipe.get().getOutput().copy();
            if (result.getItem() instanceof BlockItem) {
                result.removeSubTag("BlockEntityTag");
            }
            return result;
        }
        return ItemStack.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot like rremoving the drop from the stack or calling the decrement function of that ItemStack but all methods had the same result.